# QGIS can't save changes to a layer

Tags: qgis, layers, attribute-table, save

I am using a layer named Faser,which I took from a program called locus GIS as ready layer,it was called power_lines_10kv30kv , I changed name to Faser  and drew the lines with it :

[image]

hier is the original layer :
[image]

when I want to save the project it says:couldn't save changes to layer Faser,couldn't add object

Konnte Änderungen am Layer Faser nicht festschreiben

```
Fehler: FEHLER: Objekt nicht hinzugefügt.
  
  Datenanbieterfehler:
      OGR-Fehler beim Erzeugen des Objekts -32: In CreateFeature(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(INSERT INTO 'power_lines_10kv30kv' ("GEOMETRY","name","power","frequency","voltage","operator","ref","cables","ground_con","lg_attach") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)):
      no such module: rtree
```

the layer has fields "name","power","frequency","voltage","operator","ref","cables","ground_con","lg_attach"  , I tried to set values to these fields, but didn't help.
I tried to delet these fields also didn't help, and showed attributes weren't deleted :

```
Konnte Änderungen am Layer Faser nicht festschreiben

Fehler: FEHLER: 9 Attribute nicht gelöscht.
  
  Datenanbieterfehler:
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 8: Failed to remove field lg_attach from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 7: Failed to remove field ground_con from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 6: Failed to remove field cables from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 5: Failed to remove field ref from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 4: Failed to remove field operator from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 3: Failed to remove field voltage from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 2: Failed to remove field frequency from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 1: Failed to remove field power from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
      OGR-Fehler beim Löschen des Felds 0: Failed to remove field name from table power_lines_10kv30kv:
     error in trigger gii_power_areals_GEOMETRY: no such module: rtree
```

Comment: Have you closed the project and restarted QGIS? Have you removed the layer from the project and reloaded it?

Comment: Is your layer a shapefile or some other dataset type?  If you run the Check Validity tool on it does it produce errors?  Can you edit and save the Checked validity layer if there are no errors, or if their are errors edit and save the output of the Fixed Geometries tool?

Comment: How did you create the GeoPackage that you are saving it into? It looks like it was created with an RTree index that QGIS does not support.